# Save and switch to different display positioning configurations - Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, linux-mint, display-settings, cinnamon

My system is Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon. I have a configuration of 3 displays.

My usual configuration with all 3 active is a little weird since the displays must be a little misaligned for the hotcorners feature to work. However I manually try to make the difference as little as possible both for practical purposes and to save GPU memory usage (as I understand it). The gist of this paragraph is, it takes a bit of time to get it manually.

My not usual configuration is when I play some games, that do not play well with multiple monitors (start on non-primary monitor, bad behavior when moved to the right monitor, etc). So, before I fire up these games, I deactivate the other two monitors and only leave the central - primary monitor on.

The problem is, I have to re-activate the other two monitors when gaming is done, and it takes some time to get the positions correct again. Therefore, I was wondering if there is any way to "save a profile" of the right positions of the monitors and switch back and forth to the 3-monitor and 1-monitor profiles with one click or one command.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed - this would be super useful.
I don't have a complete solution, but I wrote this script to change resolution for just one monitor. Perhaps you could develop it for your situation?

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT=`xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/{print $2}'`
LO="1920x1080"
HI="3840x2160"
SCREEN="DP-3"

if [ "$CURRENT" = "$LO" ]; then
    xrandr --output $SCREEN --mode 3840x2160;
    echo Set to $HI; else
if [ "$CURRENT" = "$HI" ]; then
    xrandr --output $SCREEN --mode 1920x1080;
    echo Set to $LO; else
echo "Didn't recognise current resolution"
fi
fi
```